# problems porting python code to python 3

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me the equivalent to the following code in python 3?

```
file_list = range(1, 20)

for x in file_list:
    exec "f_%s = open(file_path + '/%s.txt', 'w')" % (x, x)
```

I need to open 19 files.  All having variable names associated with them.

Comment: using exec is **always** a bad idea, and there's always another better way to do it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might I recommend a better code that doesn't require `exec`?

```
import os
file_list = range(1, 20)

f = {}
for x in file_list:
    f[x] = open(os.path.join(file_path, '{0}.txt'.format(x)), 'w')
```

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to use a dictionary instead of creating different names of variables using `exec`:

```
f = {x:open('{}/{}.txt'.format(file_path, x), 'w') for x in range(1, 20)}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`exec` is now a function](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax) in Python 3. And you should use [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
exec("f_{0} = open(file_path + '/{0}.txt', 'w')".format(x))
```

Besides, there is no reason to use this. As others have pointed out, a simple dictionary should work:

```
d = {}
for i in range(1,20):
    d['f_'+str(i)] = open(file_path + '/{}.txt'.format(i), 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad way to open a list of files.  Use a list:

```
import os
file_path = '.'
files = [open(os.path.join(file_path,'{}.txt'.format(i)),'w') for i in range(1,20)]
```